# Libgdx show score and add 1 to score every second

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx, scoring

I want to increment the score by 1 point every second but I am struggling to get it to work properly.

e.g.

(pseudo code):

```
int score = 0f // on create

updateEverySecond() {
    score += 1;
    displayScore()
}
```

I would also like to know how to display the score at the top of my screen and centred.

My Full Source Code:

```
package com.ryanwarren.dodge.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class libgdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;
Texture player;

Vector2 position;

float time = 0f;

@Override
public void create () {     
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    player = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player.png"));

    position = new Vector2((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - (player.getWidth()/2)),50);     
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
        position.y += 1f;
    }
    if((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) && (position.x > 0)) {
        position.x -= 2f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
        position.y -= 1f;
    }
    if((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))  && (position.x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - player.getWidth())) {
        position.x += 2f;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        System.out.println("application clicked");
    }

    if((Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() >= 0) && (position.x > 0)) {
        position.x -= 2f;
    }
    else if((Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() < 0) && (position.x < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - player.getWidth())) {
        position.x += 2f;
    }

    System.out.println("Rotation: " + Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX());

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(player, position.x, position.y);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}
}
```

Comment: Dumping sourcecode and saying something along the lines of "make it do this" is not the best way to get useful answers on stackoverflow.com.  You might want to consider looking at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then framing your question a little differently....

Comment: You can increment it just like you did and make a bitmapfont and draw it. Its not very hard just google it. And if yoi want it centered you could use bitmap font to get the width and divide that by 2 and then subtract that from half the screen width. Want an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
float timeState=0f; 

public void render(){
// ............
timeState+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
if(timeState>=1f){
// 1 second just passed
   timeState=0f; // reset our timer
    updateEverySecond(); // call the function that you want
}
```